# jQuery autohide element after 5 seconds

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Is it possible to automatically hide an element in a web page 5 seconds after the form loads using jQuery?

Basically, I've got

```
<div id="successMessage">Project saved successfully!</div>
```

that I'd like to disappear after 5 seconds. I've looked at jQuery UI and the hide effect but I'm having a little trouble getting it work the way I want it to.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            function runEffect() {

                var selectedEffect = 'blind';

                var options = {};

                $("#successMessage").hide(selectedEffect, options, 500);
            };

            $("#successMessage").click(function() {
                runEffect();
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I'd like the click function to be removed and add a timeout method that calls the runEffect() after 5 seconds.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    // setTimeout() function will be fired after page is loaded
    // it will wait for 5 sec. and then will fire
    // $("#successMessage").hide() function
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#successMessage").hide('blind', {}, 500)
    }, 5000);
});
```

**Note**: In order to make you jQuery function work inside setTimeout you should wrap it inside

```
function() { ... }
```

Comment: I tried this code on my website. But, it didn't work. Other than this js script, what else do i need to make it work? Please advice! Thank you!

Comment: @Jornes make sure that this script is located after `<script src="jquery.js"></script>` on your page.

Answer (score 237):

```
$('#selector').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
```

Comment: Be warned that this solution breaks $('html').click(function() {
  //click outside
  $("#selector").fadeOut();
 });

Answer (score 13):

You can try :

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#successMessage').fadeOut('fast');
}, 30000); // <-- time in milliseconds
```

If you used this then your div will be hide after 30 sec.I also tried this one and it worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

Please note you may need to display div text again after it has disappeared.
So you will need to also empty and then re-show the element at some point.

You can do this with 1 line of code:

```
$('#element_id').empty().show().html(message).delay(3000).fadeOut(300);
```

If you're using jQuery you don't need setTimeout, at least not to autohide an element.

Answer (score 3):

I think, you could also do something like...

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $(".message-class").trigger("click");
}, 5000);
```

and do your animated effects on the event-click...

```
$(".message-class").click(function() {
    //your event-code
});
```

Greetings,

Answer (score 2):

You use setTimeout on you runEffect function :

```
function runEffect() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        var selectedEffect = 'blind';
        var options = {};
        $("#successMessage").hide(selectedEffect, options, 500)
     }, 5000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery(".success_mgs").show();
setTimeout(function(){ jQuery(".success_mgs").hide();},5000);

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can set the timeout after you click.

```
$(".selectorOnWhichEventCapture").on('click', function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".selector").doWhateverYouWantToDo();
    }, 5000);
});
```

//5000 = 5sec = 5000 milisec