# ASP.net control similar to auto-hide feature of Visual Studio toolbox

Tags: asp.net

First off, I'm sorry if the title doesn't explain this very well.

I'm looking for an asp.net control that works similarly to the Visual Studio toolbox's auto-hide. In other words, when not needed, it can be "unpinned" and will slide off to the side of the screen. When needed, it can be opened and pinned to stay in place. I'd rather not do it myself using javascript if a (free) control already exists. Does anyone know of such a control? If not, has anyone implemented this type of functionality using a js library with good results? Any pointers?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

[The collapsiblePanel](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/CollapsiblePanel/CollapsiblePanel.aspx) might work, I don't have any experience with it, but it's open source software from CodePlex.

I don't know of any free ASP.Net controls. But if you want to get it working using javascript you can do so with jQuery.
[This post on StackOverflow shows how to get the autohide feature working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683363/jquery-autohide-element-after-5-seconds)

Comment: I don't want it to disappear (jQuery hide). The collapsible panel may fit the bill. I'll look into it more.

Comment: I've decided to use the jQuery UI toggle function. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We use Telerik's RadSplitter. It is exactly what you are looking for.

Unfortunately, it is not free. But it worths checking out since their licensing is very flexible.

[Telerik RadSplitter](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/splitter/examples/sp_tabview/defaultcs.aspx)

Comment: Damn. That is exactly what I'm looking for, but since it's not free, I can't use it. Thanks.