# django message once logged in

Tags: django, django-templates

I would like to know how to display the greeting message "Welcome User, You are logged in" once the user login and it should vanish within 5 seconds.

The message will be displayed once after the user's successful login but not again on the consecutive visit of the home page during the same session. Because I have taken username in session in the home.html.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [django's messaging framework](https://gist.github.com/2049936) and [wrap the login view:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990502/django-signal-when-user-logs-in)

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.views import login

def custom_login(request,*args, **kwargs):
    response = login(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
         messages.info(request, "Welcome ...")
    return response
```

and in your template somewhere:

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

along with some [jquery to hide any message after 5 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683363/jquery-autohide-element-after-5-seconds):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.messages').delay(5000).fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: But where can i customize the message. Default message "You have been signed in" is coming.Please suggest me

Comment: In the view. You pass the message you want to display in the `messages.info(request, "THIS IS MY MESSAGE")`

Answer (score 7):

Note that you can use the [`user_logged_in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#topics-auth-signals) signal to add the message when the user logs in, instead of wrapping the login view, as pastylegs does in his answer.

```
# include this code somewhere it will be imported when the application loads
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in

def logged_in_message(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    """
    Add a welcome message when the user logs in
    """
    messages.info(request, "Welcome ...")

user_logged_in.connect(logged_in_message)
```

You then display the message and use javascript in the same way as pastyleg's answer.