# CSS Auto hide elements after 5 seconds

Tags: css, animation, transition

Is it possible to hide element 5 seconds after the page load?
I know there is [a jQuery solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683363/jquery-autohide-element-after-5-seconds).

I want to do exactly same thing, but hoping to get the same result with CSS transition.

Any innovative idea? Or am I asking beyond the limit of css transition/animation?

Comment: It is possible, but I would not recomend doing it. Use jQuery or pure JS for that.

Comment: here's an example: http://jsbin.com/xofaq/1/edit?html,css,output
I know there's an answer already, but I was doing it as well and kids took me away for a while :)

Comment: Appreciate it @balexandre, +1 for your comment.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

## **YES!**

But you can't do it in the way you may immediately think, because you cant animate or create a transition around the properties you'd otherwise rely on (e.g. `display`, or changing dimensions and setting to `overflow:hidden`) in order to correctly hide the element and prevent it from taking up visible space.

Therefore, create an animation for the elements in question, and simply toggle `visibility:hidden;` after 5 seconds, whilst also setting height and width to zero to prevent the element from still occupying space in the DOM flow.

## [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/M2B9B/14/)

CSS

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#hideMe {
    -moz-animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 5s forwards;
    /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 5s forwards;
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 5s forwards;
    /* Opera */
    animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 5s forwards;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes cssAnimation {
    to {
        width:0;
        height:0;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes cssAnimation {
    to {
        width:0;
        height:0;
        visibility:hidden;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div id='hideMe'>Wait for it...</div>
```

Comment: Nice! Was just about to recommend keyframes! +1!

Comment: why you do not animate the opacity?
`opacity:1` to 0

Comment: It works, but I have a question, in your answer, you only included @keyframe and @-webkit-keyframes, I wonder whether it is OK without -moz and -o. Just another question. And I found out that it just wait for 5 seconds and hide the element immediately without animation. I think it would be great if you include fade out transition part as well in your answer.

Comment: @Alfred - I'd add in the browser specific prefixes- the above is only a demo

Comment: @Radian - opacity doesnt change the fact the element will still take up space...just not be visible (http://jsfiddle.net/467bb/) - you can see the grey bordered div not collapsing on the content after 5s

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you sir!

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: How quickly could one modify this to do the exact opposite: to reveal a hidden element?

Answer (score 23):

based from the answer of @SW4, you could also add a little animation at the end.

```css
body > div{
    border:1px solid grey;
}
html, body, #container {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#container {
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
#hideMe {
    -webkit-animation: cssAnimation 5s forwards; 
    animation: cssAnimation 5s forwards;
}
@keyframes cssAnimation {
    0%   {opacity: 1;}
    90%  {opacity: 1;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes cssAnimation {
    0%   {opacity: 1;}
    90%  {opacity: 1;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<div>
<div id='container'>
    <div id='hideMe'>Wait for it...</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Making the remaining 0.5 seconds to animate the opacity attribute.
Just make sure to do the math if you're changing the length, in this case, 90% of 5 seconds leaves us 0.5 seconds to animate the opacity.

Comment: I like this solution.  Is there a way to combine it so that it fades out and then removes it from the DOM?

Comment: You'd need to use some JavaScript if you wanted to remove it from the DOM. If you meant visibly removing it from the document flow then you could use the technique above that mentions setting `height: 0` and `width: 0` - however it comes with caveats as it can cause jumping effects when changing height from 0 to 100%, etc, while also leaving the item focusable using the keyboard.

Answer (score 15):

Of course you can, just use `setTimeout` to change a class or something to trigger the transition.

HTML:

```
<p id="aap">OHAI!</p>
```

CSS:

```
p {
    opacity:1;
    transition:opacity 500ms;
}
p.waa {
    opacity:0;
}
```

JS to run on load or DOMContentReady:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById('aap').className = 'waa';
}, 5000);
```

[Example fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/68CUh/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I just wanted not to use javascript at all. If I wished to use javascript or jQuery, I may use jQuery solution I have included in my question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Please keep in mind that [jQuery is not even remotely a synonym to Javascript](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/219504). You asked for a solution that doesn't use jQuery's built in transitions, and I gave you an answer with pure CSS transitions and a single line of generic Javascript. You never asked for a solution without JS, the answer is thus complete.

Comment: Up voting just to make people realize that jQuery != JS

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes that is like somebody saying no java and then you give them a GWT solution. Or somebody saying no css and you giving a sass solution. The tags on the question are css, not javascript or jquery. Jquery is synonymous enough with javascript as it's a framework around it.

Comment: @snowe2010 not quite. SASS would mean installing a compiler. GWT would mean including an extra library. jQuery means installing and loading an extra library. I therefore assumed the question was how to achieve the intended results with only the means available in a vanilla browser, which kinda boils down to CSS and plain Javascript. The most straightforward and less hacky of those 2 solutions was provided in this answer. The accepted answer is nice, but imo not as clean as this one. Opinions differ, doesn't make the answer in itself wrong.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes yes except that he explicitly stated that he knew there was a jquery solution and he wanted a css solution. If he knew there was a jquery solution then there is obviously a javascript solution, since jquery is just a library to make javascript easier.

Comment: Oh and please don't consider jQuery a synonym to JS, it would be part of the ECMAScript standard if it wasn't such a huge pile of steaming poo. jQuery is a terrible collection of hacks built to lure bad programmers into thinking they know Javascript. I never use it, neither do any of the professional web developers I know.

Comment: jQuery was a great library that actually inspired additions to the core CSS DOM libraries without which the world would probably still be using jQuery. Just because the world moved on and surpassed jQuery does not make Jon Resig's accomplishments worth any less! I suggest anyone to read jQuery's source code and learn from it. Yes it's using some patterns that have become out of fashion but you have to view a library in the context of the time it was made and at the time it was fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try **fadeOut**?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#plsme').fadeOut(5000); // 5 seconds x 1000 milisec = 5000 milisec
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='plsme'>Loading... Please Wait</div>
```

fadeOut (Javascript Pure):

[How to make fadeOut effect with pure JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29017379/how-to-make-fadeout-effect-with-pure-javascript)

Comment: The question was about using CSS, not JavaScript!

Answer (score 1):

you can hide elements on load and then show and animate them after some delay using CSS and keyframes as below

```
   // keyframes fadeIn Animation
   @keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {
     transform:scale(0,0);
     visibility:visible;
      opacity:0;
    }
     100% {
       transform:scale(1,1);
       visibility:visible;
       opacity:1;
      }
     }

    // CSS class
      .containerDiv {
       visibility:hidden;
       animation: fadeIn 3s forwards 3s;

      }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

[CSS Auto hide elements after 5 seconds in vue js all tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrhDk.png)

```
.tooltip {
    -webkit-animation: cssAnimation 1.5s forwards; 
    animation: cssAnimation 1.5s forwards;
}
@keyframes cssAnimation {
    0%   {opacity: 1;}
    50%  {opacity: 1;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes cssAnimation {
    0%   {opacity: 1;}
    50%  {opacity: 1;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}
```

Comment: .tooltip {
    -webkit-animation: cssAnimation 1.5s forwards; 
    animation: cssAnimation 1.5s forwards;
}
@keyframes cssAnimation {
    0%   {opacity: 1;}
    50%  {opacity: 1;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes cssAnimation {
    0%   {opacity: 1;}
    50%  {opacity: 1;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).