# How to make fadeOut effect with pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, fadeout

I'm trying to make fade out effect for a `div` with ***pure JavaScript***.

This is what I'm currently using:

```
//Imagine I want to fadeOut an element with id = "target"
function fadeOutEffect()
{
 var fadeTarget = document.getElementById("target");
 var fadeEffect = setInterval(function() {
  if (fadeTarget.style.opacity < 0.1)
  {
   clearInterval(fadeEffect);
  }
  else
  {
   fadeTarget.style.opacity -= 0.1;
  }
 }, 200);
}
```

The div should fade out smoothly, but it immediately disappears.

What's wrong? How can I solve it?

[jsbin](http://www.jsbin.com/kepaho/1/edit)

Comment: are you see 9 errors in your code that show jsbin?

Comment: also check value for `fadeTarget.style.opacity`, if you don't setup manually `style` - it empty

Comment: Really? My jsbin hasn't got any error.

Comment: your jsbin show 9 error like: _Line 27: Expected a conditional expression and instead saw an assignment._

Comment: My jsbin's console is just empty.

Comment: hm, it shown on _javascript_ tab, methinks you add wrong link to old variant

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Initially when there's no opacity set, the value will be an empty string, which will cause your arithmetic to fail. That is, `"" < 0.1 == true` and your code goes into the `clearInterval` branch.

You can default it to 1 and it will work.

```js
function fadeOutEffect() {
    var fadeTarget = document.getElementById("target");
    var fadeEffect = setInterval(function () {
        if (!fadeTarget.style.opacity) {
            fadeTarget.style.opacity = 1;
        }
        if (fadeTarget.style.opacity > 0) {
            fadeTarget.style.opacity -= 0.1;
        } else {
            clearInterval(fadeEffect);
        }
    }, 200);
}

document.getElementById("target").addEventListener('click', fadeOutEffect);
```

```css
#target {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="target">Click to fade</div>
```

An empty string seems like it's treated as a 0 by JavaScript when doing arithmetic and comparisons (even though in CSS it treats that empty string as full opacity)

```
> '' < 0.1
> true

> '' > 0.1
> false


> '' - 0.1
> -0.1
```

**Simpler Approach**
We can now use [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) to make the fade out happen with a lot less code

```js
const target = document.getElementById("target");

target.addEventListener('click', () => target.style.opacity = '0');
// If you want to remove it from the page after the fadeout
target.addEventListener('transitionend', () => target.remove());
```

```css
#target {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

```html
<p>Some text before<p>
<div id="target">Click to fade</div>
<p>Some text after</p>
```

Comment: Additional: Why does the opacity stop at 0.1 but not 0?

Comment: just change `fadeTarget.style.opacity < 0.1` to `fadeTarget.style.opacity == 0`

Comment: @Anakin fixed, in this case, it's because I knew it started with 1, but it would fail if it started at .91 for example.

Comment: This snippet fails on undefined fadeTarget if you switch page during the execution.

You should check for null fadeTarget  before trying to access it.

Comment: @Jean-SimonCollard Feel free to add checks that are necessary in your code, I'd rather not pollute the example and I specially don't like blanket null checks https://dzone.com/articles/why-i-never-null-check-parameters

Comment: dont forget to add a fadeTarget.style.display = 'none' with the else; to remove the div

Comment: @EwaldBos Not everyone wants it to stop occupying space. You may also just  remove it from the DOM instead.

Comment: @JuanMendes true as well, just in case

Answer (score 34):

Just this morning I found this piece of code at http://vanilla-js.com, it's very simple, compact and fast:

```
var s = document.getElementById('thing').style;
s.opacity = 1;
(function fade(){(s.opacity-=.1)<0?s.display="none":setTimeout(fade,40)})();
```

You can change the speed of the fade changing the second parameter in the `setTimeOut` function.

```js
var s = document.getElementById('thing').style;
s.opacity = 1;
(function fade(){(s.opacity-=.1)<0?s.display="none":setTimeout(fade,40)})();
```

```css
#thing {
  background: red;
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="thing">I will fade...</div>
```

Comment: I much prefer the OP's code, looks like that vanilla-js is trying to win an obfuscation context. I love that website though

Comment: I would probably raher say a minifaction contest and in times where mobile internet speeds of 64 kbit/s and Lower is still common it's good to minify stuff.

Comment: @My1 Not to minify the stuff you post in answers, you let minifiers do that to production code

Comment: curious how you could re-write this to fade in?

Comment: Beautiful recursion!

Answer (score 20):

It looks like you can do it another way(I may be wrong).

```
event.target.style.transition = '0.8s';
event.target.style.opacity = 0;
```

Comment: CSS transition works, it even works better in real life. But, I wanted a pure javascript-based animation.

Comment: Why @Anakin? CSS is far more efficient than JS timers.

Comment: This thread is old. Back then, I was doing this solely for learning-purposes. In practical uses, I don't see a reason this should be implemented over CSS transition either.

Answer (score 7):

you can use CSS transition property rather than doing vai timer in javascript. thats more performance oriented compared to what you are doing.

check

http://fvsch.com/code/transition-fade/test5.html#test3

Comment: While a valid point, this should be a comment, the OP wants to know what is wrong with their code, it was very close to working

Comment: @JuanMendes :- i am new here. I dont have enough points to add comments. I can comment in my question and answer only.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the accepted answer, we now have [WAAPI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API/Web_Animations_API_Concepts) which basically adds animation API to JavaScript.

For example,

```js
/**
 * @returns {Object}
*/
function defaultFadeConfig() {
  return {      
      easing: 'linear', 
      iterations: 1, 
      direction: 'normal', 
      fill: 'forwards',
      delay: 0,
      endDelay: 0
    }  
}

/** 
 * @param {HTMLElement} el
 * @param {number} durationInMs
 * @param {Object} config
 * @returns {Promise}
 */
async function fadeOut(el, durationInMs, config = defaultFadeConfig()) {  
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {         
    const animation = el.animate([
      { opacity: '1' },
      { opacity: '0', offset: 0.5 },
      { opacity: '0', offset: 1 }
    ], {duration: durationInMs, ...config});
    animation.onfinish = () => resolve();
  })
}

/** 
 * @param {HTMLElement} el
 * @param {number} durationInMs
 * @param {Object} config
 * @returns {Promise}
 */
async function fadeIn(el, durationInMs, config = defaultFadeConfig()) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {         
    const animation = el.animate([
      { opacity: '0' },
      { opacity: '0.5', offset: 0.5 },
      { opacity: '1', offset: 1 }
    ], {duration: durationInMs, ...config});
    animation.onfinish = () => resolve();
  });
}

window.addEventListener('load', async ()=> {
  const el = document.getElementById('el1');  
  for(const ipsum of "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor \uD83D\uDE00".split(' ')) {
    await fadeOut(el, 1000);  
    el.innerText = ipsum;
    await fadeIn(el, 2000);
  }
});
```

```css
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="el1" class="text-center">...</h1>
```

Comment: FTW. 2022 and I hadn't heard of `animate()`! I love your use of `await` in a `for` loop to produce incredibly easy to read animation code.

Comment: Much better than all other `setInterval` "solutions"

Comment: I really like this solution (just implemented it in one of my projects) thanks for sharing! Wonder if the browser compatibility is sufficient though when using on commercial websites? Has someone experiences with that or used a polyfill successfully?

Answer (score 4):

```js
function fadeOutEffect() {
    var fadeTarget = document.getElementById("target");
    var fadeEffect = setInterval(function () {
        if (!fadeTarget.style.opacity) {
            fadeTarget.style.opacity = 1;
        }
        if (fadeTarget.style.opacity > 0) {
            fadeTarget.style.opacity -= 0.1;
        } else {
            clearInterval(fadeEffect);
        }
    }, 200);
}

document.getElementById("target").addEventListener('click', fadeOutEffect);
```

```css
#target {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="target">Click to fade</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution

```
function fadeOut(selector, timeInterval, callback = null) {

    var fadeTarget = document.querySelector(selector);

    let time = timeInterval / 1000;
    fadeTarget.style.transition = time + 's';
    fadeTarget.style.opacity = 0;
    var fadeEffect = setInterval(function() {

        if (fadeTarget.style.opacity <= 0)
        {
            clearInterval(fadeEffect);
            if (typeof (callback) === 'function') {
                callback();
            }
        }
    }, timeInterval);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While most of the solutions in this and other SO threads work, here are my two cents. If you want to rely only on pure JS ONLY then this should do the trick:

```
   function fadeOutEle(el) {
        el.style.opacity = 1;
        (function fade() {
            if ((el.style.opacity -= .009) < 0) {
                el.style.display = "none";
            } else {
                requestAnimationFrame(fade);
            }
        })();
    };
```

The Key here is the `el.style.opacity -= .009` which give a cool fade out effect. Keep it below 1/2 a second (0.009 in this case) so that the effect is visible before the element hides.

Answer (score 0):

I needed some custom fading, so I came up with this solution.
The methods are added to the HTMLElement prototype for an easier workflow.
Supports a fadeIn to display:flex and can fadeIn to a predefined opacity value from data-op attribute(didn't need it for fadeOut, but that's an easy upgrade).
The method returns `this`, for chaining..

```js
(()=>{
    const ndt = () => +new Date(),
        anim = (f) => (window.requestAnimationFrame && requestAnimationFrame(f)) || setTimeout(f, 16),
        fader = (el, time, out, last, flex = false) => {
            if (!el.style.opacity) el.style.opacity = out ? '1' : '0';
            const op = el.dataset.op ?? '1';  
                hide = () => {
                    el.style.display = 'none';
                    el.style.opacity = '0';
                },
                show = (done) => {
                    el.style.display = !flex ? 'block' : 'flex';
                    if (done) el.style.opacity = op;
                },
                calc = (o, t) => out ? o - t : o + t,
                tick = () => {
                    el.style.opacity = calc(+el.style.opacity, (ndt() - last) / time);
                    last = ndt();
                    const o = +el.style.opacity,
                        a = out && o > 0 || !out && o < +op;
                    console.log('opacity', o)
                    if (!a) return out ? hide() : show(true);
                    anim(tick);
                };
            if (!out) show(false);
            tick();
        };
    HTMLElement.prototype.fadeIn = function (time, flex = false) {
        fader(this, time, false, ndt(), flex);
        return this;
    };
    HTMLElement.prototype.fadeOut = function (time) {
        fader(this, time, true, ndt());
        return this;
    };
})();

const parent = document.getElementById('parent');
document.getElementById('fadeIn').addEventListener('click', e=> {
  parent.fadeIn(1000, true);
});
document.getElementById('fadeOut').addEventListener('click', e=> {
  parent.fadeOut(1000);
});
```

```css
div#parent {
  display: flex;
}
div#parent div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
div#red {
  background: red;
}
div#green {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<button id="fadeIn">fadeIn</button>
<button id="fadeOut">fadeOut</button>
<div id="parent" style="display:none;" data-op="0.5">
  <div id="red"></div>
  <div id="green"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did found this code and thought I share it with you all because I think its a very good solution because its short, clean and a great use of a immediately invoked function expression (IIFE):

```
/**
 * element fade out
 * @param {object} el - element to fade out 
 */
fadeOut(el)
{
    // start with 100% visibility
    el.style.opacity = 1;
  
    // fade to 0% visibility
    (function fade() {

        // remove element when done fading
        if ((el.style.opacity -= .03) < 0) el.remove(); 
      
        // tell browser i want animation
        else requestAnimationFrame(fade);

    })();
}
```

**Code explanation:** Its a recursive function. The `-=` counts the Opacity down until less then zero. The recursion stops automatically when Opacity is less then zero because the recursion is in the requestAnimationFrame function.

`requestAnimationFrame` is better as `setInterval()`: https://builtin.com/software-engineering-perspectives/requestanimationframe

I display my pages from server. When there is a message to be displayed, like "Comment is posted" I make sure with this function the message is fade out after a period of time and after that the element is deleted from the page.

**Additional:** I did not offer an extra parameter to the function but you could set an optional `interval` parameter with default value `.03` and replace `.03` in the code with `interval`