# Iframe fadeout event without Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to translate a piece of application to pure Javascript (without Jquery) and I'm stuck in this piece of code:

```
window.parent.$("#iframeMain").fadeOut(function(){
    window.parent.$("#iframeSecondary").fadeIn().contents().find(".div").html(divContent);
});
```

Any idea how to do this with pure Javascript?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29017379/how-to-make-fadeout-effect-with-pure-javascript

Comment: I don't think so. What I really need is to capture the fadeOut event or something equivalent.