# Javascript equivalent to jQuery .show(200) with transition?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, css-transitions, transition, show

I know `$(".box").show();` is Jquery is the same as `document.querySelector(".box").style.display = "block";` in JS. However, when `.show(300)` has a transition fade on it, I can't seem to replicate that in JS.
Upon, `'mouseenter'`, a small tooltip box pops up. Currently I have:

```
let svgTarget = document.querySelector('svg #target' + newId);
svgTarget.style.fill = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.0)';

svgTarget.addEventListener('mouseenter', function (e) {
 d3.select('svg #tooltip' + newId)
  .transition()
  .duration(5000)
  .style("display", "inline");
 inOutBehavior(e, hoverState);
},)
```

**The `'mouseenter'` functionality works there's just no smooth transition, it's instantaneous**. I'm using D3 to implement the transition but with no luck. I have also tried using an event listener with D3 but that also did not work. Is there a solution with vanilla JS or D3 that I am not seeing? Thanks!

Comment: can't you simply apply a CSS style and have it hook up to [an animation](https://animista.net/play/entrances/fade-in)? why persuing javascript at all for fading?

Comment: Yes you're right, just wondering if there's a way to do it with JS. Also, could you show me an example of applying CSS style and hooking it up to an animation?

Comment: @JoeSpinelli Not trying to be rude, but have you tried it? StackOverflow is not a place to ask for suggestion. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29017379/how-to-make-fadeout-effect-with-pure-javascript/29017547#29017547

Comment: @JuanMendes I haven't worked with css animation yet so I've been struggling. Sorry about that, I'll do more research. Thanks for the resource!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the opacity rather than the display? I tried the following, and it seemed to fade into view in the way you described.

```
tooltip.transition().duration(5000).style("opacity", 0.9);
```

Let me know if this doesn't work, or if you have any questions!

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this without D3, then you could use transition-delay CSS option.

```
transition-delay: 200ms;
transition: opacity 1s ease;
```

Here is an example.. https://codepen.io/soichih/pen/LYGeorr

You can not animate the `display` state.