# Fadein in pure javascript not working. Why?

Tags: javascript, fadein, fadeout

I found this code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29017677 .
This is fadeOut function. It's working

```
var s = document.getElementById('thing').style;
s.opacity = 1;
(function fade(){(s.opacity-=.1)<0?s.display="none":setTimeout(fade,100)})();
```

```js
var s = document.getElementById('thing').style;
s.opacity = 1;
(function fade(){(s.opacity-=.1)<0?s.display="none":setTimeout(fade,100)})();
```

```css
#thing {
  background: red;
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="thing">I will fade...</div>
```

now I am trying to write a function for fadeIn like the fadeOut function. But this function doesn't work. I do not understand why.

```
var s = document.getElementById('thing').style;
s.opacity = 0;
(function fade(){(s.opacity+=.1)>0.95?s.display="block":setTimeout(fade,100)})();
```

```js
var s = document.getElementById('thing').style;
s.opacity = 0;
(function fade(){(s.opacity+=.1)>0.95?s.display="block":setTimeout(fade,100)})();
```

```css
#thing {
  background: red;
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="thing">I will fade...</div>
```

Comment: Here's my take: https://jsfiddle.net/4ndorgLs/

Comment: Looking at your code I have no idea why it's failing but from logging it it seems like `s.opacity+=.1` has no effect. Logging `s` before and after gives 0, then 0.1, then keeps giving 0.1. Again, no idea what's happening there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `+=` is trying to append, so keep with `-=` and set your .1 to negative value as `-0.1` and it will works.

```js
var s = document.getElementById('thing').style;
s.opacity = 0;
(function fade() {
    (s.opacity -= -0.1) < 1 && setTimeout(fade,100);
    }
)();
```

```css
#thing{
  background: red;
  line-height: 40px;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="thing">I will fade...</div>
```

Complementing my answer with [Chris G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5734311/chris-g)'s comment:

> The opacity is a string, so appending 0.1 works the first time: "0" + "0.1" is "00.1" which checks out. Then it's "0.1" + 0.1 which is "0.10.1" and gets parsed back into "0.1" - [Chris G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5734311/chris-g)

Comment: Nice catch! The opacity is a string, so appending 0.1 works the first time: `"0" + "0.1"` is `"00.1"` which checks out. Then it's `"0.1" + 0.1` which is `"0.10.1"` and gets parsed back into `"0.1"`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for your case would be to use more CSS instead of JS, you can add the property `transition` to the `#thing` selector and then all you need to do is set the opacity via JS code(no need to add timeouts or any other form of complicated handling)

```js
function hide() {
  document.getElementById('thing').style.opacity = 0
}

function show() {
  document.getElementById('thing').style.opacity = 1
}
```

```css
#thing {
  transition: .4s
}
```

```html
<div id="thing">I am showing up</div>
<button onclick="hide()">hide</button>
<button onclick="show()">show</button>
```

Comment: More on transition attribute here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Comment: [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) is more information on CSS Transitions. Note that there's quite some flexibility with transitions if one makes use of `transition-delay`, `transition-property`, `transition-duration` and `transition-timing-function`.

Comment: @BrenoPrata [Please do not use, recommend or link to w3schools.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com) (also, while this provides a valid alternate solution, it doesn't really answer OP's question. They specifically ask why their code fails, and your answer doesn't address that)

Comment: Great solution! I'll test it.