# Show hidden div on :hover, and make div stay visible for 5 seconds after mouseout on CSS / CSS3

Tags: html, css, tooltip, duration

I have the following **div** on my **html** page:

```
<div class="tooltip">
    <span>content</span>
</div>
```

And the following **css** script:

```
.tooltip span {
    display:none;
}
.tooltip:hover span {
    display:inline;
}
```

Is there a way to make the span stay visible for more 5 seconds after the mouse is out of the div? The reason I'm trying to do this is because this tooltip has some content inside it such as links.

Comment: you need to add some js. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Timers

Comment: @hunzaboy really? this can't be done on css / css3?

Comment: You can do it but the approach might be different. Read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21993661/css-auto-hide-elements-after-5-seconds

Comment: You could try it with `opacity` and `transition`, but I think thats not what you're searching for. Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/3zaz28L6/

Comment: @hunzaboy yea this isn't really what I'm looking for, visibility and opacity are not very helpful for me... thanks for the research though!

Comment: @user3050478 Pure CSS in my solution bro!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PURE CSS**

Sorry, I forgot. `Display` doesn't get affected by transitions.

Use `opacity` instead.

Use transitions:

```
.tooltip span {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0s 1s;
}
.tooltip:hover span {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0s;
}
```

```css
.tooltip span {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0s 5s;
}

.tooltip:hover span {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0s;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">
  <span>content</span>
</div>
```

If you want it to fade out, use  this:

```
.tooltip span {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0s 5s;
}
.tooltip:hover span {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0s;
}
```

```css
.tooltip span {
  opacity: 0;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  transition: all .4s 4.6s;
}

.tooltip:hover span {
  opacity: 1;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all .4s;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">
  <span>content</span>
</div>
```

**UPDATE** use `all` if you have multiple properties. Note: you generally need have an initial property and a changed property. E.g. See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/494ohcm9/1/) (working)

Comment: Hi @ChrisHappy, I tested it and it did fade after 5 seconds, but what if the span has other attributes such as `position: absolute;`, borders, backgrounds, etc... Should I add `transation` to them aswell?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my attempt!

HTML

```
<div class="tooltip">
  Title
  <span> - content</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.tooltip span {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.tooltip:hover span {
  visibility: visible;
}

.tooltip span:not(:hover) {
  visiblity: hidden;
  transition: visibility 5s;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mpx3m1v4/

Answer (score 1):

jQuery solution:

```js
$( ".tooltip" ).mouseover(function() {
   $('.tooltip span').show();
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.tooltip span').hide('slow', function(){
 });// or fade, css display however you'd like.
}, 5000); // set visible time
});
```

```css
.tooltip span {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="tooltip">
  tooltip
    <span>content</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to give only css based solution

Answer (score 0):

Pure css. This isn't perfect. Try this.

```
.tooltip span {
    //display:none;
    display: block;
}
.tooltip:hover span {
    //display:inline;
    -webkit-animation: opacity1 0.1s 1 forwards;
    animation: opacity1 0.1s 1 forwards;
}

.tooltip:not(:hover) span{
  -webkit-animation: opacity0 0.1s 1 forwards;
    animation: opacity0 0.1s 1 forwards;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
    animation-delay: 5s; 
}

@-webkit-keyframes opacity1 {
    to {opacity: 1; height: auto; width: auto;}
}
@keyframes opacity1 {
    to {opacity: 1; height: auto; width: auto;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes opacity0 {
    to {opacity: 0; height: 0; width: 0;}
}
@keyframes opacity0 {
    to {opacity: 0; height: 0; width: 0;}
}
```