# show website after css animation

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm in the process of making a website.  I found this link to create a spinning animation.

[CSS3 Rotate Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771225/css3-rotate-animation)

I want to be able to display this animation for 4s and then have it fade to the website.  I only have knowledge in html and css so it would be great if someone could please help me.

Comment: You probably want something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21993661/css-auto-hide-elements-after-5-seconds

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function(){$("body").hide().fadeIn(1000);});

Comment: This answer assumes they are using jQuery, which they never stated in the post or the tags.

Comment: Thanks. Good Point and Answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for hear but my best guess is that you want to use the answer from that question you linked as a loading image in front of a website and you want the image to fade out and the website to fade in after a specified length of time.

To perform an action after a specified length of time you use

```
setTimeout(function, duration)
```

[Documentation on setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

To hide/show the image/website respectively you can use something like this:

```
function(){
  document.getElementById("content").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
}
```

Then you combine them into this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById("content").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
}, 4000);
```

You can also jQuery to be able to animate the transition:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $("#content").show(1000);
  $("#loading").hide(1000);
}, 4000);
```

And here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kLphoptj/) that demonstrates that it works.