# Print html message for a few seconds

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-blade

This is my code :

```
return redirect()->action('AdminController@index')->with('succes', ['Mission Ajoutée']);
```

in blade :

```
@if(Session::has('succes'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ Session::get('succes')}}
    </div>
@endif
```

I would like to print this message for 10secs. Is is possible to do this with a blade template or with HTML? I want to achieve this without using Javascript.

Comment: Why don't you want to use javascript?

Comment: You can't control the DOM like that without javascript.

Comment: may help this with CSS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46798683/css-hide-element-after-5-seconds-show-it

Comment: use Session::flash('succes', 'Mission Ajoutée') instead of with(...)

Comment: i dont want to use JS cause it's a project for my degree, and i'm evaluated on the backend, i dont want to loose 20h to learn JS for cool effect. if i could that with no js it's cool but if i cant idc