Run css loading animation on hover once (at page loading)
I am making a css loading animation for a div that will show movie details on hover. Here is my html code:
<div class="tooltips "><img src=".." alt="img">
    <div class="toolcon">
      <div class="plc">
        <div class="loadingContainer1">
          <div class="ball1"></div>
          <div class="ball2"></div>
          <div class="ball3"></div>
          <div class="ball4"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tooldiv ">
            movie details
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

and here is my css code :
.tooltips:hover{
 .toolcon{
     display: block;
     background: transparent;
     backdrop-filter: blur(60px);
     opacity: 1;
     div{display: block;}
         }
}

.loadingContainer1{animation: fadeout 1.8s linear forwards;}

@keyframes fadeIn{
    0%{display: flex;}

    100%{display: none;}
}

Everything works fine but every time I hover the loading animation runs. I want the animation to run only once on hover every time the page loads. Is there a way to do it with CSS only?

I think you would need to use javascript to do something like this. Something along the lines of on hover check if animation_finished is false, if so then run animation and then set animation_finished to true. Here's a link with similar implementation except without the hover aspect: https://www.karinabaha.com/posts/play-css-animation-only-once-per-website-visit

I suppose you could also have an element with a :hover animation, that hides itself afterwards (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21993661/css-auto-hide-elements-after-5-seconds) and then with a duplicate element underneath without an animation. That would be possible without Javascript, but would require you to be able to replicate the end-state of the animation in a still state on the element underneath if you want the transition to be smooth.
