# Auto-Hide ViewBag Message in C# after 15 seconds

Tags: c#, viewbag

I am displaying a message via ViewBag in C# and it works fine. Now what I want is to auto Hide the ViewBag message after 15 seconds. How should I do that?

Following is my code where I am using ViewBag:

```
public ActionResult ForgetPassword(String EmailId, string message)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = message;
        ForgetPassword objForgetPassword = new ForgetPassword { EmailId = EmailId };
        return View();
    }
```

//Other Model where I am passing the Message

```
 if (objResult.Status)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", new { message = "Password changed Successfully. Please Login with the New Password."});
            }
```

CSHTML code for the same:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal for-pass">
    <h4><b>@ViewBag.Message</b></h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OTP, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OTP, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OTP, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This has less to do with ViewBag and more to do with hiding anything on a page after 15 seconds. The simplest would be to assign an id to the h4 containing the message and add an onload handler that uses setTimeout to call a function after 15 seconds. In that function you just hide the div, generally by setting style "display: none".

Comment: You can place the viewbag value in a html control and write a timer on the controller so that it can hide after a certain time limit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the javascript [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function to run the code to hide the message using the query [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#msg").fadeOut();
    }, 15000);
});
```

and in view:

```
<h4 id="msg"><b>@ViewBag.Message</b></h4>
```

here's fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3Sw1O9

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript **setTimeout()** function to do so.

Give your label an particular Id like '**lblMsg**'

```
setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById('lblMsg').style.display = "none"; }, 15000);
```

Or Simply you want to remove the element after 15 seconds.

Using JQuery you can use **remove()** function.

```
setTimeout(function(){ $('#lblMsg').remove(); }, 15000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS to hide element which contains `ViewBag` data like this:

```
setTimeout(function() { $("h4").hide(); }, 15000);

$("h4").delay(15000).fadeOut();
```

Or using CSS selector `display: none`:

```
setTimeout(function() { $("h4").css('display','none'); }, 15000);
```

Make sure the `h4` is the only one element which contains the message, otherwise use `<div>` with `id` attribute.

Answer (score -1):

Give an id to the container of the message. Then add document.ready method that hide the container after 15 sec. Use settimeout function as below:

```
setTimeout(function() {
        $("#successMessage").hide('bind', {}, 500)
    }, 5000);
```

Comment: are you sure this will hide after 15 seconds ?

Comment: Definitely. just use it correctly. Try it out. The view that renders the message should have this code.

Comment: can you please provide a working example fiddle if you dont mind ?

Comment: before copy pasting atleast read the question and understand the content and test the code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683363/jquery-autohide-element-after-5-seconds

Comment: the fiddle you are provided is using some other code than this.You told me that this code will work in this scenario.

Comment: it is using the same code, I just gave an id to the message container and document.ready hiding the message.

Comment: can you make it working using setTimeout(function() {
        $("#successMessage").hide('blind', {}, 500)
    }, 5000); this code ?

Comment: ohh common man!!! Just change 5000 to 15000...I set it for 5sec just to make it quicker. This is so so simple thing.

Comment: that might be simple for you. but the question is different and your answer is different. and still i couldn't find any working examples with the code you have provided over here.

Comment: Then please start from scratch... you really need to sharpen up basics. This is tooo basic thing. I suggest you to practice more and more.

Comment: May be you can help me on this I guess , if you can then please provide me a working fiddle with the solution you have posted here.

Comment: what exactly the issue with this fiddler I shared ? I will help you out

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/erpuneetgoel507/xpvt214o/898326/ now it is for 15 sec

Comment: the issue is you are using   $("#banner-message").fadeOut(); im the fiddle and the posted answer is something else . I am asking you a working fiddle with the answer you have posted here.

Comment: could you replace your settimeout with setTimeout(function() {
        $("#successMessage").hide('blind', {}, 500)
    }, 5000);  this and make it work ?

Comment: try this now.. I just added the code to your code https://jsfiddle.net/erpuneetgoel507/7vpd10oc/

Comment: see both settimeout doing same thing. Fade out is hiding by fading and this simple hides. Rest is same.