# how to display a div for 10 seconds and then hide it using JQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css

i have a div i.e

```
<div class="msg-panel" id="mydiv"></div>
```

CSS code:

```
 .msg-panel {
        position: absolute;
        height: 35px;
        width: 200px;
        background-color: green;
        top: 30%;
        left: 50%;
        color: #fff;
        display: none;
        border-radius: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

i want to display this div for ten seconds on button click.

can you help me for this
thanks.

Comment: what have you tried so far? I see no script that shows that you even attempted to solve this on your own.

Comment: If you have yet to try anything, check out the [click](https://api.jquery.com/click/) method for listening for the click event when a button is clicked, the [delay](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) method for waiting the 10 seconds, and the [hide](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) method for actually hiding the div.

Comment: `$('.msg-panel').show().delay(10000).hide();`

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/683363/519413

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(function() {
    $(".msg-panel").show()
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".msg-panel").hide()
    }, 10000);
});
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks! updated, now it should work.